# Generalization of the Jacobi-Anger expansion to higher harmonics

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, bessel-functions

I know the [Jacobi-Anger expansion relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Anger_expansion) which gives the Fourier development of $e^{i z \cos(\theta)}$ and ${ e^{i z \sin(\theta)} }$, such that
$$
\begin{cases}
e^{i z \cos(\theta)} = \sum\limits_{n} i^{n} \mathcal{J}_{n} (z) \, e^{i n \theta} \, ,
\\
e^{i z \sin(\theta)} = \sum\limits_{n} \mathcal{J}_{n} (z) \, e^{i n \theta} \, , 
\end{cases}
$$
where ${ \mathcal{J}_{n} }$ are Bessel functions of the first kind.

I am interested in possible generalizations of this relation to higher harmonics. Are there any known results for the Fourier development of
$$
e^{i z \cos(2 \theta)} \;\;\; \text{and} \;\;\; e^{i z \sin(2 \theta)} \;\;\; \text{?}
$$
More generally, are there know results for $e^{i z \cos(n \theta)}$ and $e^{i z \sin (n \theta)}$, with ${ n \in \mathbb{N}}$ ?

Any enlightning references are also, of course, welcome.

Comment: Your series should have a $e^{\color{red}{n}i\theta}$ in place of $e^{i\theta}$. Given that, what's wrong in simply replacing $\theta$ with $k\theta$ in the given Fourier series?

Comment: As Jack notes, going from $\theta\to n\theta$ is a trivial substitution. A non-trivial generalization would be to add another harmonic to the periodic function, e.g. $\sin \theta\to \sin\theta+a \sin 2\theta$. This results in the usual single-variable Bessel functions being replaced with multivariate generalizations. See this [paper](https://www.dmi.unict.it/ojs/index.php/lematematiche/article/download/376/353) for details.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thank you, I corrected the mistake. Sometimes, I really feel stupid. You're definitely right. Using this substitution, one has $e^{i z \sin(k \theta)} = \sum_{n | n \equiv 0 [k]} \mathcal{J}_{n/k} (z) e^{i n \theta}$. Fortunately shame does not kill...

Comment: @Semiclassical Thank you for the reference. Indeed, more complex cases such as $e^{i (z \sin(\theta) + w \sin (2 \theta) )}$ are also of interest for me. Maybe I should rephrase my question so as to rather consider this case ?

Comment: It would be an interesting question, though you'll want to do a search of previously asked questions first to avoid overlap.